# Prove that zero is the only element in this family of nested intervals

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I'm proving that

$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}\left[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right]=\{0\}$$

for my real analysis class. I shall not make use of limits since we have not covered them yet. For the proof I use the following theorems (these theorems may be found in Bartle's Introduction to Real Analysis 4th ed. Lemma 2.3.4 and Theorem 2.5.3):

**Theorem 1 (approximation property):** Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $A\ne\varnothing$, and $A$ is bounded. Then a lower bound $b$ for $A$ is the greatest lower bound for $A$, i.e. $b=\inf A$, iff for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $a_\varepsilon\in A$ such that $b+\varepsilon>a_\varepsilon$.

**Theorem 2:** Let $\mathcal{G}=\left\{[a_n,b_n]:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+, a_n\le a_{n+1},b_n\ge b_{n+1}\right\}$ be a countable family of closed nested intervals, that by the Cantor's Nested Intervals Theorem we know $\cap\mathcal{G}\ne\varnothing$. Thus, if $\inf(\{b_n-a_n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\})=0$, then $\cap\mathcal{G}=\{x\}$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$, i.e., the set $\cap\mathcal{G}$ has only one element.

*Proof*: Let $\mathcal{F}=\left\{[-1/n,1/n]:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\right\}$, and $I_n\in\mathcal{F}$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a countable family of closed nested intervals, by Cantor's Nested Interval Theorem we know that $\cap\mathcal{F}\ne\varnothing$. Now we show that $\cap\mathcal{F}$ has only one element.

Consider the set $A=\left\{1/n-(-1/n):n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\right\}$, then

i) Since by definition $2/n>0$ for any integer $n$, then $0$ is a lower bound for $A$.

ii) Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. By the Archimedean Property, we know that there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $\varepsilon/2>1/m,$ i.e., $0+\varepsilon>2/m$. Note that $2/m\in A$. Hence, considering that $0$ is a lower bound for $A$ by Theorem 1, we may conclude that $0=\inf A$. Furthermore, by Theorem 2 the previous result implies that $\cap\mathcal{F}$ is a singleton.

Now we show that $0\in\cap\mathcal{F}$. Suppose $0\notin\cap\mathcal{F}$, thus there is an $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $0\notin I_n$, that is $0\notin[-1/n,1/n]$, implying that $0<-1/n$ which is impossible, thus $0\in\cap\mathcal{F}$. Hence, $\cap\mathcal{F}=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}\left[-1/n,1/n\right]=\left\{ 0 \right\}$.
$\square$

Is this proof correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

> Since by definition, $\frac{2}{n} > 0$ for any integer $n$.....

This is a minor point but it isn't really true. What you meant to say was that for any positive integer $n$, $\frac{2}{n} > 0$. Also, this typically isn't a statement "by definition". Rather, it's something you can prove from the field/order axioms.

> Suppose $0 \notin \bigcap \mathcal{F}........

Right, so you're doing a proof by contradiction here. That's not really necessary, though. See, you already know that:
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+: 0 \in \left[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n} \right]$$
So, it follows, by definition, that $0$ belongs to the intersection of all of these closed intervals. I'm not saying your argument there was wrong or anything; it's just that a contradiction wasn't exactly needed. Of course, it's good that you're trying to be creative and come up with your own proofs.

---

Now, you needn't have actually used those Cantor's Intersection Theorem for this. You already know that $\{0\} \subseteq \bigcap \mathcal{F}$ by virtue of the last part of what I said above. Let $x \in \bigcap\mathcal{F}$. Then:
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+: x \in I_n$$
If $x \neq 0$, then $|x| > 0$. Using the Archimedean property, we can find an $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $m > \frac{1}{|x|}$. Or to re-phrase, we can find such an $m$ with the property that $|x| > \frac{1}{m}$. This implies that $x \notin I_m$ and that is impossible. So, it follows that $x = 0$ and we're done.